# Skeleton Meteor application not updating across tabs

Tags: javascript, meteor

I installed a fresh copy of Meteor on Linux with the `curl | sh` command, and on Windows with the Meteor client.

When I run the following series of commands:

```sh
$ meteor create testcode
$ cd testcode
$ meteor run
```

Meteor starts up the app, and gives me the message of the app running on `http://localhost:3000/`.

When I open up the page in two tabs in my browser, and click on the <kbd>Click Me</kbd> button, the "You've pressed the button `Y` times" text **does not update** with `Y+1` in both tabs, only the current tab. The click counts are no longer synced across the tabs.

Is this expected behavior? Because I remember seeing it work by syncing the number across tabs in early revisions.

To wit, I've tried this in Linux/Windows with Chrome & Firefox / Chrome & Internet Explorer, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supposed to.

You might have confused it with the leaderboard example app that can be created using:

```
$ meteor create --example leaderboard my_leaderboard
```

The default skeleton application only changes a local reactive variable.
Here is the [source code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/tools/static-assets/skel) for it.

It creates a template named `hello`.

The `hello` template's markup includes a reference to a helper called `counter` and a button.

```
<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
</template>
```

`Session` is a reactive dictionary ([ReactiveDict](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict)) provided by the [*session*](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session) package, and is not synced between browser tabs.
It is set to `0` on startup and is reactively accessed by the `counter` helper.

The helper is rerun whenever the variable changes and triggers a change to the DOM.

```
// counter starts at 0
Session.setDefault('counter', 0);

Template.hello.helpers({
  //rerun whenever the Session's couter value changes
  counter: function () {
    return Session.get('counter');
  }
});
```

The `hello` template's event handler increments the value every time the button is clicked, which triggers a rerun of the `counter` helper.

```
Template.hello.events({
  'click button': function () {
    // increment the counter when button is clicked
    Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') + 1);
  }
});
```

Comment: Okay, sorry, I was gravely mistaken.

Comment: Well, this might be a common misunderstanding with new users. What made you think that it should sync?

Comment: I somehow still clearly remember seeing in early demos that when one user clicked on the number in one tab, it would update on the other tab...

Comment: Well, AFAICT, the skeleton app has been this way (and even less reactive) [since the beginning](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commits/8b5399efe2edfeb00006041d13bb153496f34b5c/tools/skel/~name~.js). Anyway, this may serve as a good FAQ.

Comment: @Kyll, I agree. Added.

Comment: Nice, but now you're kind of contradicting yourself. _"only changes a local reactive var"_ vs _"Session is a reactive variable that exists globally by default."_ =p

Comment: Yepp. To be clear, it's in the "global" scope of the `window` object :)